# Does glMatrix scale transformation require an specific order under WebGL?

Tags: 3d, webgl

I'm trying to do scale transformation with glMatrix for WebGL.

Scale transformations work nicely when I use the following order:

```
mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [1, 1, 1]);
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(zAngle), [0, 0, 1]);
mat4.scale(mvMatrix, [2, 2, 2]);
```

But the object is not re-scaled when scaling transformation is performed first:

```
mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
mat4.scale(mvMatrix, [2, 2, 2]);
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [1, 1, 1]);
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(zAngle), [0, 0, 1]);
```

Must the scaling happen always as the last transformation command?

Thanks,
Everton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258910/opengl-scale-then-translate-and-how) answer to understand about "stacking" transformations in OpenGL. And of course, matrix multiplication isn't commutative so you will get different results based on the order.