# Render ellipse using libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am attempting to render an ellipse using ShapeRenderer, and have come up with the following partial solution:

```
void drawEllipse(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    float r = (width / 2);
    ShapeRenderer renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setProjectionMatrix(/* camera matrix */);
    renderer.begin(ShapeType.Circle);
    renderer.scale(1f, (height / width), 1f);
    renderer.circle(x + r, y, r);
    renderer.identity();
    renderer.end();
}
```

This draws an ellipse at the specified coordinates with the correct width and height; however, it appears that the scale transformation causes the circle to be translated in the viewport, and I have not been successful in determining the mathematics behind the translation. I am using an orthogonal projection with y-up where the coordinates map to a pixel on the screen. I am not very familiar with OpenGL.

How can I draw an ellipse using libgdx, and have it draw the ellipse at the exact coordinates I specify? Ideally, that would mean that the origin of the ellipse is located in the top-left corner, if the ellipse was contained in a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

The new Libgdx `ShapeRenderer` API (current nightlies, in whatever release will come after v0.9.8) contains an [ellipse drawing method](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html#ellipse%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20int%29) so you can ignore the rest of this answer.  The `ShapeRenderer` method has changed in other ways, too though (e.g., the `ShapeType` is just `Filled`, `Line`, or `Point` now).

For folks stuck with the older API, you should be able to work-around the distortion by making sure the scaling happens around the origin.  This is a standard OpenGL practice (so its a bit obtuse, but they're following OpenGL's lead).  See [Opengl order of matrix transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993339/opengl-order-of-matrix-transformations) and [OpenGL: scale then translate? and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258910/opengl-scale-then-translate-and-how).  Even better (again standard OpenGL practice) you end up listing the operations in the reverse order you want them to happen at, so to make a circle, distort it into an ellipse, then move it to a specific destination you actually write code like:

```
renderer.begin(ShapeType.Circle);
renderer.translate(x, y, 0);
renderer.scale(1f, (height/width), 1f);
renderer.circle(0, 0, r);
renderer.end();
```