# Not understanding OpenGL transformations

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

So I've started learning OpenGL and started out by trying to do some things in 2D. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the transformations to work properly.

Here's some code:

```
glm::mat4 Transform;
Transform = glm::scale(Transform, glm::vec3(2*(image.Size.x/renderTarget.Size.x),2 * (image.Size.y/renderTarget.Size.y), 1));

Transform = glm::translate(
    Transform,
    glm::vec3(2 * (Position.x / renderTarget.Size.x) - 1.0f,2 * (-Position.y / renderTarget.Size.y) + 1.0f,1)
    );
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniTrans, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Transform));
```

and the shape I'm trying to draw:

```
    float verts[] = {
        0.0f,0.0f,
        1.0f,0.0f,,
        1.0f,-1.0f,
        0.0f,-1.0f
    };
```

The point of this is that I'm converting the regular OpenGL coords (with (0,0) in the middle) to having the origin at the top left. Unfortunately the scaling really messes with the position, moving it If I turn that off then the position works fine, but I have no idea why.

Comment: It would help if you did those two operations in the opposite order. GLM and OpenGL both use column-major matrices and post-multiplication. The proper order of transformations is therefore Translate, Rotate, Scale.

Comment: Okay, so switching the order worked, but I don't understand why. Everything online says scale-rotate-translate.

Comment: It is because you effectively read OpenGL code in reverse, so the bottom most opengl instruction in your code is effectively the one you want to be happening first (this is majorly condensed and summarised)  I will dig out some reference material to illustrate the workings and reasonings as soon as I can:)

Comment: Similar explanation at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2259263/1903417 :)

Comment: @user1152717: That is the correct mathematical order, but OpenGL uses column-major matrices and post-multiplication as I mentioned first. This means that the first matrix operation *effectively* occurs last. It is a very handy property that makes OpenGL's legacy matrix stack useful; frequently changing object transformations are at the top of the stack and viewing transformations are at the bottom. If GL used row-major matrices like D3D does, then the viewing transformation would need to be on the top of the stack, which would make transforming individual objects a real nuisance.

Comment: marked both up, as you explain both well:)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman couldn't they just use left multiplication a.k.a. the transposed operation

Comment: That could be done, but then the API would need to pre-multiply row-major matrices. Both GL and D3D post-multiply, the only difference between them is that one uses row-major and the other column-major.